# Is it possible to do pic collage (compositing nodes)?

Tags: python, animation, compositing-nodes, masking

[image: Layout example]
[image: Layout example]

I would like to build a python script that takes in entry a list of pictures, set them into a layout like in the above pictures, animate the pictures (ken burns effect) and render. 
I would like to know if it is possible to something similar in blender?
I would like to know if the layout could be animated too?
I guess it could be done with the compositor and creating and manipulating masks but i don't know how to do it, so some resources would be welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: I doubt you could do that with the compositor alone, or at least it would be unnecessarily challenging; but it might be possible to do directly in a 3D scene

Comment: it's totally possible, but not very comfortable. Is there a reason why you want do do it in blender? there are a lot of programs that can do that task easier and faster.

Comment: Hi guys, thank you for your comments. The reason why i want to it in blender is that i want to create a template and a script so i can call it automatically to render videos. I think it could be easier to do with after effects but i am on ubuntu and prefer to use blender which can be scale out on a cluster of machine for free. So if you have any suggestions it would be very helpful even if i have to use different features of blender.